# ITK image allocation and sysmalloc

Tags: c++, malloc, itk

I am currently inheriting old code and trying to run it. As part of this there is an image generation done through ITK (which has been built and installed on the system)

The (truncated) function causing issue at the moment is the following

```c
void PrintDensityImage(std::vector<float> *HU, imageDimensions dimensions, std::string nameFile)
{
        ImageType::Pointer image = ImageType::New();
        ImageType::RegionType region;
        ImageType::IndexType start;
        start[0] = 0;
        start[1] = 0;
        start[2] = 0;

        ImageType::SizeType size;
        size[0] = 512;//dimensions.nbVoxel.x;
        size[1] = 512;//dimensions.nbVoxel.y;
        size[2] = 8;//dimensions.nbVoxel.z;

        ImageType::SpacingType inputSpacing;
        inputSpacing[0] = 0.9;//dimensions.voxelSize.x;
        inputSpacing[1] = 0.9;//dimensions.voxelSize.y;
        inputSpacing[2] = 1.1;//dimensions.voxelSize.z;

        std::cout << inputSpacing << endl;
        std::cout << size << " " << start << " " << region << endl;

        region.SetSize(size);
        region.SetIndex(start);

        image->SetRegions(region);
        image->SetSpacing(inputSpacing);
        printf("I hit here...\n");
        std::cout << region << endl;
        image->Allocate();
        printf("But I do not get here\n");
        ImageType::IndexType pixelIndex;
        
        .........
}
```

And the header includes

```
#include <itkImageFileReader.h>
#include <itkImageFileWriter.h>

#include <itkHDF5ImageIO.h>

#include "itkGDCMImageIO.h"
#include "itkGDCMSeriesFileNames.h"
#include "itkNumericSeriesFileNames.h"
#include "itkImageSeriesReader.h"

typedef itk::Image< float, 3 > ImageType;
```

The current console output is

```
[0.9, 0.9, 1.1]
[512, 512, 8] [0, 0, 0] ImageRegion (0x7ffd0e7a6910)
  Dimension: 3
  Index: [0, 0, 0]
  Size: [0, 0, 0]

I hit here...
ImageRegion (0x7ffd0e7a6910)
  Dimension: 3
  Index: [0, 0, 0]
  Size: [512, 512, 8]
```

Followed by the error

```
CT_GPUMCD: malloc.c:2379: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I am not certain what is the cause of this error but it seems to spur from the `image->Allocate()` line which I can't quite grasp why. As far as I can read from the ITK docs (https://itk.org/ITKSoftwareGuide/html/Book1/ITKSoftwareGuide-Book1ch4.html) this should be fine.

If there is any insight into the matter I would greatly appreciate it as I really don't see what the issue is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from `malloc.c`, so from C run-time library. Are you using some experimental or beta version of compiler? Or some modified CRT? Or some software which replaces malloc by their own version (e.g. to track memory leaks)? I doubt this has much to do with ITK. What happens if you replace `image->Allocate();` by `float * p = new float[512*512*8];`?

For reference, `Allocate` is [here](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/blob/v5.3rc03/Modules/Core/Common/include/itkImage.hxx#L46-L54), which boils down to [new T[size]](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/blob/v5.3rc03/Modules/Core/Common/include/itkImportImageContainer.hxx#L176-L180).

Comment: I don't think this is a beta compiler but it is a bigger project run through first make and has a bunch of it's own gpu memory allocation that I had hoped were not the cause of this. I did replace the line like you showed and still got the same error, so yeah it would seem to *not* be an ITK issue but something else firing. Thank you for the insight.

Comment: ITK is normally used with CMake, so I doubt that is the issue either. Failing assertions in `malloc.c` is rare and strange.

Comment: I had another quick look at this, and shouldn't it be `int size_img = 512*512*8*sizeof(float);
float * p = new float[size_img];`
When running this it doesn't encounter the malloc error, but a seg fault further down the line (presumable due to image not having anything allocated)

Comment: When you do `new char[10]`, 10 bytes are allocated. If you `new float[10]`, 40 bytes are allocated. If you invoked `malloc` directly, then you would need to fiddle with `sizeof(float)`.